# Combine mysql result set(rows) into just one single row

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql result set that has several rows, what i would like to do is to combine the rows to form one row of results depending on the uniqueness of the rows. Say I have this:

Table result 1

```
Labref | Medium_Day | Comonent | Generic_results
-------------------------------------------------
A      |    1       |    ab    | A=5
-------------------------------------------------
A      |    1       |    ab    | R=10
-------------------------------------------------
A      |    1       |    ab    | N=5
-------------------------------------------------
A      |    7       |    cd    | A=7
-------------------------------------------------
A      |    7       |    cd    | R=6
-------------------------------------------------
A      |    7       |    cd    | N=3
-------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to produce something like this

```
Labref | Medium_Day | Comonent | Generic_results
-------------------------------------------------
A      |    1       |    ab    | A=5% (R10, N=5)
-------------------------------------------------
A      |    7       |    cd    | A=7% (R=6, N=3)
-------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried to use the normal "SELECT * FROM `component_summary` WHERE `labref`='A'" Then use a function in the application side to do this but its not working...

Any Suggestions to do it with mysql first

Comment: at first look , your db is not normailzed

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
SELECT Labref, Medium_Day, Comonent,
 CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Generic_results), ',', 1),
  '% (',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Generic_results), ',', 2),
  ',',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Generic_results), ',', 3),
  ')'
 ) AS gen_results
FROM component_summary
GROUP BY Labref
```